# Выпадающее меню JQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Изучаю Jquery. Делаю выпадающее меню.
Вот код

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
$('.menu li ul').hover(
function(){
$(this).addClass("active");
$(this).find('ul').SlideDown();
},
function(){
$(this).removeclass("active");
$(this).find('ul').SlideUp('fast');
}
);
});
</script>
    </head>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
<center>
    <img src="http://....................">
</center> 
    </div>
<div class="menu">
{menu}

<li> Пункт</li>
<ul>
<li> punct1</li>
<li>punkt2</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Но оно не хочет ни сворачиваться и вообще ничего не делает. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

найденные мной ошибки:

1. сначала надо скрыть элементы дочернего списка (подменю);
2. SlideUp и  SlideDown - пишутся с маленькой буквы;
3. элементы подменю должны находится внутри элемента меню. т.е. `ul`, в котором находится подменю должен быть дочерним по отношению к `li`, при наведении на который это подменю появляется. Вы же сформировали набор `$('.menu li ul')`...так почему у Вас `ul` является не дочерним к `li` в DOM-дереве, а сестринским?

в общем, смотрите мой код и сравнивайте со своим. у меня всё работает.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#menu li#submenu ul').hide();
    $('#menu li#submenu').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
        }, function(){
            $(this).find('ul').slideUp('fast');
        });
});
</script>
    </head>
<body>

<div id="menu">
 <ul>
    <li id="submenu"> Пункт
        <ul>
            <li> punct1</li>
            <li>punkt2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

UPD **Убрал специфические классы и элементы, которые на отображение меню не влияют абсолютно. класс `.menu` заменил на `id="menu"`. Для элемента `li`, содержащего подменю, добавил `id="submenu"` для наглядности**

UPD2 повторите html перед началом изучения jQuery ибо Вам необходимо чёткое понимание принципов построения DOM-дерева.

Comment: Снимаю шляпу и благодарю! Спасибо за помощь!