# Появление при нажатий

Tags: jquery, html, css

Здраствуйте.
Столкнулся с проблемой, никак не могу ее решить.
Так вот нужно сделать чтобы при нажатий на текст или картинку внизу появлялись подпункты.  Пример:
[image]
  Заранее благодарен!

HTML:

```
<div id="button"><a href="#">Все потоки</a><img src="img/rows.png"    class="menu_class" /></div>
<div class="fade">
<ul class="first">
<li><a href="#">Общество</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Мода</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Кино</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Музыка</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Город</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="second">
<li><a href="#">Лукбуки</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Плейлисты</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Клипы</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Арт-Хаус</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Люди</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').click(function () {
    $('#button').addClass('active');
    $('div.fade').fadeToggle('medium');
    });
});
```

Но добавление класса почему то не работало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пишем обычный навигационный блок с подменю. затем подменю скрываем. при возникновении события `click()` отображаем пункт меню.

UPD эти вопросы уже не раз поднимались!!!например, вот здесь [Выпадающее меню на jQuery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/56148/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-jquery) и вот [Выпадающее меню на CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/52381/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-css?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#52444)
Вторая ссылка хоть и не совсем по теме вопроса, но суть остаётся прежней независимо от способа решения на jQuery или на CSS

сделайте ссылку и изображения блочными по всей высоте раздела. мне кажется это происходит из-за того, что события `div#button` не происходило (были клики по ссылке или изображению). если так делаем и хотим получить событие для родительского элемента, тогда на раздел должен быть "повешен" обработчик, который будет получать событие от дочернего элемента. Почитайте про обработку событий в jQuery (фазы всплытия и захвата).
В общем, попробуйте сделать дочерние элементы блочными и пропишите для них события, что, если кликаем по ссылке или по изображению, добавляем класс для родительского раздела. а при добавлении этого класса показываем скрытые списки.

Comment: обновил тему, посмотрите пжлст

Comment: а зачем два разных списка, если они должны одновременно появляться? мне кажется вместо события `.click()` в данном случае лучше использовать `.toggle()` (я так понимаю, меню должно появляться при первом клике, при втором скрываться). соответственно, класс `active` должен добавляться и удаляться. а как Вы проверяли, что класс не добавляется?

Comment: чтобы списку с классом fisrt поставить float:left; 
примите дружбу в маиле пжлст

Comment: так это сразу можно в свойствах этого элемента прописать. выстроить эти два блока рядом друг с другом и скрыть. при возникновении нужного события - оба показать.

Comment: не забываем закрывать вопросы!)

Comment: сделал чтобы при наводке появлялись списки, но как только я уберу мышь с ссылки то все исчезает. тоесть все появляется и исчезает но нажать на то что появляется исчезает нельзя

Comment: если Вы делали через метод `.hover()` такого быть не может, потому что в этом методе используются события `mouseenter` и `mouseleave`. при возникновении этих событий, при переходе в дочерние элементы - событие продолжает "существовать".